# File Reference Events(IO Error SecurityError) Questions AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, ioerror

How do i test the IOError and SecurityError events on flash? Is there a way to put these events to the test? I just want to know if it really works so i can add more codes on it.

Answer (score 0):

Sure - try to load non-existing website, or try to load data (or even swf) from secured website that does not allow you to.. :) For the latter - you can easily put `crossdomain.xml` with deny to your server in order to test it.